# Powershell: How to send an email to each person with different information in a same pattern?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I'm facing this situation. I've got the examination results(scores) of the students in the class. And I need to let everybody get their score separately without knowing others' scores. 
The score is saved in an Excel file(or some other type of files), just like [scores information saved in an Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeslI.png) showed.
And I've got these students' email addresses in my outlook, which is showed in [contacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKpKx.png).
I'm wondering, is it possible to send everybody an email with their score information, which the information is clearly in a same pattern, using Powershell? 
In my work, I always encounter this situation, that I need to send each person an email with some information, that is different for each person but in a same pattern. If some help me with this, I will be really appreciate.

Comment: can you post an example script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: There are many [existing scripts](https://www.google.com/#q=powershell+send+email+using+addresses+from+csv).

Comment: Wow, that is so cool! I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There you go :)

```
$csv = import-csv path\to\csv\book2.csv

foreach ($c in $csv) { 
    $name = $c.name
    $score = $c.score
    $Body = "

<p style='text-align: justify; direction: rtl;'><font face='verdana'>Hello $name</font></p>
<p style='text-align: justify; direction: rtl;'><font face='verdana'>Your Score is: $score</font></p>
<hr width='1px'; size='500px'; color='#4169E1';>                 

"
    }

$password = "Put your secure password here" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "your username@domain.com"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
Send-MailMessage -From youraddress@domain.com -To $RecipientsTo -Subject "Score" -BodyAsHtml $Body -SmtpServer "server.domain.com" -Credential $Credential -Encoding UTF8
```

Change path to `csv` `password` `username` and parameters in `send-mailMessage`
you should supply a csv with `name email score` columns.
The only command that may give you error is `send-mailmessage`, my example is using microsoft exchange account.

Comment: No problem, Just accept the message and upvote so we can help others too.